# SQL Server: Best technique to regenerate a computed table

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

We have a few tables that are periodically recomputed within SQL Server. The computation takes a few seconds to a few minutes and we do the following:

1. Dump the results in computed_table_tmp
2. Drop computed_table
3. Rename computed_table_tmp to computed_table. (and all indexes).

However, we seem to still run into concurrency issues where we have our application requesting a view that utilizes this computed table at the precise moment where it no longer exists.

What would be the best technique to avoid this type of problem while ensuring high availability?

Answer (score 3):

If this table is part of your high-availability requirement, then you can't do this the way you've been doing it.  Dropping a table in a production SQL environment breaks the concept of high availability.

You *might* be able to accomplish what you're trying to achieve by creating [one or more partitions on this table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787.aspx).  A partitioned table is divided into subgroups of rows that can be spread across more than one filegroup in your database.  For querying purposes, however, the table is still a single logical entity.  The advantage of using a table partition is that you can move around subsets of your data *without breaking the integrity of the database*, i.e., high-availability is still in place.

In your scenario, you'd have to modify your process such that all activity takes place in the production version of the table.  The new rows are dumped in to a separate partition, based on the value of your [partition function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510234.aspx).  Then you'll need to [switch](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the partitions.

One of the things you'll need to do is identify a column in your table that may be used as the partition column, which determines which partition a row will be allocated to.  This might be, for example, a datetime column indicating when the row was generated.  You can even use a computed column for this purpose, provided it is a PERSISTED column.

One caveat:  Table partitioning is not available in all editions of SQL Server... I don't believe Standard has it.